# Object injection in java

Tags: java, cdi, ejb-3.0

I am using EJB 3.0 and CDI in a new project and these techs are pretty new to me. As per me, EJB beans(marked with @local/@Remote, @Stateless/@Stateful) are managed by EJB containers and can be injected anywhere into the system. So is the case with CDI beans(marked with @RequestScoped).

Now what I want is to inject a POJO or a JPA entity into my ejb bean ? Is that possible ? When I try to inject them using @Inject , looks like old replicate of these objects(with prepopulated values) is injected into the system.

PS: I am not using spring FW.

Comment: You can in theory inject anything with a custom producer, but it's not necessarily a good idea.  Is that your only/real question, or is there some broader issue you're trying to solve but are asking a specific question about CDI?

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: Actually, I understood where I was wrong. I was assumed doing @Inject Obj obj is equivalent to Obj obj = new Obj();